# Find the set of solutions to a infinite polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I was trying to solve $e^x = x$ and after expanding:
$1+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+x^4/4! ... = 0$ I don't know what to do. Right now I am interested in 2 things: Is there a way to find a closed form for the 0's for the infinite expression, maybe even factor it? (Clearly not in the reals) and second: Within the reals is there a general solution for $e^{a+x} = bx$. I am not looking for any approximations because anyone can do that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is there a way to find a closed form for the 0's" no

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$, the roots of $e^{a+x} = bx$ is given by various branches of $-W(-\frac{e^a}{b})$ where $W(\cdot)$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the real solutions.
By the expansion, for $x\geq 0$,
$$e^x-x=1+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+x^4/4!+\dots\geq 1$$
Moreover for $x<0$, $0<e^x=x<0$, so there are no real solutions.

P.S. Over $\mathbb{C}$, the solutions of $\exp(z)=z$ are infinite and they are related with the [Lambert W functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (no closed form unfortunately).
See the green dots in this picture taken from  [an interesting paper](http://www.ebyte.it/library/docs/math16/2016_MATH_Sykora_FixedPointsExp.pdf) by Stanislav Sykora.
[image]

Comment: I said "Clearly not in the reals". Quite obviously no solution in the reals exists.

Comment: @mtheorylord Sorry for wrong guessing. I edited my answer with some comments on the complex case.